# how to update AWS ECS Container Agent on Fargate launch type instances

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, amazon-ecs, aws-fargate

I am trying to configure AWS ECS using awsvpc mode with an IAM role to use specifically for tasks. Our ECS instances are of fargate launch types. After specifying a Task IAM role in the task configuration, we ssh into our task and try to run awscli commands and get the following error:
`Unable to locate credentials. You can configure credentials by running "aws configure".`

In order to troubleshoot, we ran the same docker image in a container with an EC2 launch type and when we ran the same awscli command, it errors by saying the assumed role does not have sufficient permissions. We noticed that this was because it was assuming the container instance IAM role, rather than the Task IAM role.

Based on the documentation [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/task-iam-roles.html#enable_task_iam_roles), it is clear that when using awsvpc networking mode, we need to set the `ECS_AWSVPC_BLOCK_IMDS` agent configuration variable to true in the agent configuration file and restart the agent in order for our instances to assume the Task IAM role rather than the container instance IAM role.

For the time being, for performance testing purposes, we need to deploy with the Fargate launch type and [according to the docs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonECS/latest/developerguide/ECS_agent.html), the container agent should be installed automatically for Fargate:

> The Amazon ECS container agent is installed on the AWS managed infrastructure used for tasks using the Fargate launch type. If you are only using tasks with the Fargate launch type no additional configuration is needed and the content in this topic does not apply.

However, we still need to be able to assume our task IAM role. Is there a way to update the necessary environment variable in the AWS-managed agent configuration file so as to allow the assuming of the task IAM role? Or is there another way to allow this?

Answer (score 0):

When creating the task definition for your Fargate Task, are you assigning a Task Role ARN? There are two IAM ARNs needed. The Execution Role ARN is the IAM role to start the container in your Fargate cluster and uses permissions to setup the CloudWatch logs and possibly pulling an image from ECR. The Task Role ARN is the IAM Role that the container has. Make sure the Task Role ARN has the ECS Trust Relationship.

```
 {
      "Version": "2012-10-17",
      "Statement": [
        {
          "Effect": "Allow",
          "Principal": {
            "Service": "ecs-tasks.amazonaws.com"
          },
          "Action": "sts:AssumeRole"
        }
      ]
    }
```

Comment: Yes I am setting both IAM roles